# Get records between specific time-frame

Tags: oracle

I am trying to pick all the records available between the time frame.

I need to take a timestamp from **TABLE2** and get all the records in **TABLE1** are available between that time and the current time.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE STATUS = 'COMPLETED' 
      AND LAST_UPDATE_USER = 'myID' 
      AND LAST_UPDATE_DT BETWEEN 
          TO_DATE((
              SELECT /*+PARALLEL(16)*/ SIGN_IN_DT 
              FROM TABLE2 
              WHERE ID = 'myID' 
                    AND SIGNED_SCREEN = 'screen1' 
                    AND SIGN_OFF_DT IS NULL), 
              'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff') 
           AND SYSDATE;
```

*Date format in both the tables* = `05-MAR-19 07.47.26.769934000 PM`

I get the exception:

> ORA-01821: date format not recognized

Please help.

Comment: What is the datatype of both columns?

Comment: Timestamp datatype.

Comment: Why do you perform `TO_DATE(...)` on a value which is already a `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`)? Just skip the `TO_DATE(...`

Comment: Don’t try converting something that is already in DATE (or TIMESTAMP) datatype into a DATE (or TIMESTAMP. You have two TIMESTAMP columns, so just compare them as-is!

Comment: Your subquery must return only 1 row. In this case `/*+PARALLEL(16)*/` seems to be rather useless.

Comment: Yes. Thanks Wernfried :)

Comment: Do you expect to have LAST_UPDATE_DT values in the future? If not then your SYSDATE comparison is redundant and you can simplify your statement to LAST_UPDATE_DT > SIGN_IN_DT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select * from table1 t1
      join table2 t2 on t1.last_update_user = t2.ID
where t1.status = 'COMPLETED'
  and t1.last_update_user = 'myID'
  and t2.signed_screen = 'screen1'
  and t2.sign_off_dt is null
  and t1.last_update_dt between t2.sign_in_dt and sysdate;
```